# Extract double from a string in c

Tags: c, floating-point, double, extract, floating-point-conversion

I want to write a function in C that has one string parameter and returns a double number.
For example when the string is `fsldnf213414fasfa` it should return `213414`.
But it should be also able to return floating points like `fasfasf123.412412fasfff` as `123.412412`.

I've already a function that can extract only integer numbers not floating points:

```
double get_num(const char* s) 
{
    unsigned int limit = UINT_MAX / 10;
    double value = 0;
    if ( !s ) {
        return 0;
    }
    for ( ; *s; ++s ) {
        if ( value < limit ) {
            if ( isdigit(*s) ) {
                value *= 10;
                value += (*s - '0');
            }
        }
        else {
            return UINT_MAX;
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Check [`strtod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof).

Comment: I've check it already but I havent found a way to return it to a double number, only extract to number + floating point + number.

Answer (score 4):

First skip over the non-digits, then use [`strtod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof) to convert the number to a `double`:

```
double get_double(const char *str)
{
    /* First skip non-digit characters */
    /* Special case to handle negative numbers and the `+` sign */
    while (*str && !(isdigit(*str) || ((*str == '-' || *str == '+') && isdigit(*(str + 1)))))
        str++;

    /* The parse to a double */
    return strtod(str, NULL);
}
```

See [here](http://ideone.com/uop4ae) for a working example.

Comment: What happens if the number is negative?

Comment: @JasonD Ah of course... Updated answer to be able to handle negative numbers.

Comment: And now it doesn't handle a leading '+' either :)

Comment: @JasonD Does now. :) Your answer is probably better though.

Comment: And for some added mess, how about a '.' without a leading 0 ? :)

Comment: @JasonD your way has to call `strtod` for each `char` I don't think that's efficient, I updated my answer to use `isalpha` instead it handles all the cases you mentioned.

Comment: also I don't think it's necessary to handle `+` at all, if a positive number skips it will still be positive.

Comment: But what if the string beginns with a number? Like 12313asfa1231? I assume it drops the following numbers...

Comment: @inix42 It doesn't "drop" them, it just doesn't get to them. You can modify the function to take a reference to the string pointer, and set it to the end of the first number (using the second argument to `strtod`) and then call the function in a loop.

Comment: Input like `".25"` fails to convert to 0.25.  (Note that decimal point might be a `','`.) Also does not recognize `NAN, INF`.  Fails when `*str < 0`.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using isdigit() or otherwise second-guessing strtod(), you can check to see whether it parsed any of the string:

```
char temp[] = "dgsgsd-3.5454dfds";

char *t1 = temp;
char *t2;
double d;

do
{
    if(*t1 == 0) return INVALID;
    d = strtod(t1, &t2);    
} while(t2 == t1++);

return d;
```

Comment: Same question here: But what if the string beginns with a number? Like 12313asfa1231? I assume it drops the following numbers...

Comment: Yes, if you expect multiple numbers in the string you would have to check for those. Your function only returns a double. If you need to return more than one number, that's not going to be enough anyway, and you'd need to either return a collection of numbers or to call it multiple times with updated input, until you run out of string.

Comment: Okay I understand, you are right. But what if I want it in one double? Like 123132afsaf123123 as 123132123123. I could extract the first numbers but how I could 'add' these to the rest?

Comment: strtod() tells you where it finished parsing, so any of the answers given here can be updated to continue parsing additional numbers in the string with minimal effort. Indeed that behaviour is how my answer actually works - t2 will point to the next character after the parsed number,and could be passed back to the caller or looped over.

Comment: Ah, you expect a single number to be split? That's different. You could create a duplicate of the string, stripping out invalid characters, and then parse that with strtod(). However I can imagine cases where the answer will be ambiguous - so I'm not sure the problem is well defined.

Comment: I was going to ask about your requirement for floating point, but I see you've added a new question about that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13701284/char-as-a-decimal-separator-in-c

Comment: Good answer.  Best to use `strtod()` for a _correct_ parsing.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (; *s; s++) {
    if (!isalpha(*s)) {
        value = strtod(s, NULL);
        break;
    }
}
```

Result:

```
"fasfasf-123.412412fasfff"
"fasfasf+123.412412fasfff"
"fasfasf.123412412fasfff"

-123.412412
123.412412
0.123412
```

Comment: How about "dgsgsd%^&£.5454dfds" ? :)

Comment: @JasonD if you expect that input, then you have to go with the slower method

Comment: The input in the question wasn't well specified, so it's hard to know which answer is best. However I'd question if my approach is much slower - I imagine strtod()'s checking is as efficient as anyone elses, and it's just a matter of function call overhead, assuming the function has not been inlined. Depending in implementation, that may be pretty minimal. Unless performance is necessary and this shows up on a benchmark, I'd not worry about the speed here...

Comment: @JasonD  yours will always work, I give you that, but a call to `strtod` logically, should do much more work than simple range checking done in `isalpha`, setting `endptr`, error checking, updating `errno` etc...also based on that, `isalpha` and similar functions are more likely to be inlined. However, the overhead is insignificant for small strings, so +1.

Comment: I think you're almost certainly correct, though it's worth mentioning that isalpha() does observe the locale, so internally it's not necessarily just a simple range check.

Comment: This fails various corner cases: `"xyz-x123"` (assumes non-alpha character always begins numeric text), `"INF123"`, (assumes an alpha  character does not begin numeric text)

Answer (score 0):

I hope to help you.

```
double stringtof(char *s) {
  int i = 0, j, k = 0;
  int llen = 0;

  llen = strlen(s);
  for (i = 0; i < llen; i++) {
    if (isdigit(s[i]) == 1) {
      break;
    }
  }

  char str2[llen - i];

  for (j = i; j < llen; j++) {
    str2[k] = s[j];
    k++;
  }
  // * val=atof(str2);
  return (atof(str2));
}
```

[ideone](https://ideone.com/UhjEXn)

Comment: Fails with input like `"-123"` to convert to -123 and `".25"` to convert to 0.25.

Answer (score 0):

To extend [@JasonD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13698811/2410359) good idea about using `strtod()`.

Complete valid strings include the below and potentially some other esoteric implementation specific ones.

```
"123.45"
" 123.45"
"+123.45"
"-123.45"
".45"
"INF"  (or maybe INFINTY)
"NAN"
"123,45"  (when , is the locale decimal point
"123e45"
"0x123p45"
```

Yet it is reasonable to assert that a numeric string is not required to begin with a control character nor space.

Could use `is....()` functions *carefully* to reject non-starters like `isgraph()`.

> The `isgraph` function tests for any printing character except space (’ ’).

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Return fail flag.
int seek_double_in_string(double *dest, const char *s) {
  if (s) {
    // Perhaps allow seek_double_in_string(NULL, s) ?
    double dummy;
    if (dest == NULL) {
      dest = &dummy;
    }

    while (*s) {
      if (isgraph(*(unsigned char*)s)) {  // Use s as-if it was `unsigned char *`
        char *endtpr;
        *dest = strtod(s, &endptr);
        if (s != endptr) {
          // Some conversion occurred - pedantic code might want to detect overflow.
          return false; // no error
        }
      }
      s++;
    }
  }

  // Form a default answer if desired like 0.0 or NAN
  *dest = 0;
  return true;
}
```